# Override Theme's CSS for a single page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes, styling

I have been through hundreds of webpages on tutorials, question forums, youtube videos, etc. I have tried editing the header.php, creating a child theme and editing the new stylesheet, and even putting parts of my css inline with the html on this page. Nothing seems to be taking full effect over the existing CSS and showing the page the way I'd like it to be.

The goal is to get the wordpress page to look like the properly styled page.

A photo of the correctly implemented design in a file I created on my localhost: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWIT9.png)

And a photo of the incorrectly implemented design when I put the HTML in to a wordpress page:  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlR8N.png)

And here is the CSS:

```
body {
font-family: "AvenirNext-Regular", Avenir, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1.5em;
color: #545454;
 }
 h1, h2, h4, h5, h6 {
color: #b1997b; 
font-weight: 600; !important
line-height: 1.3em; !important
font-family: "AvenirNext-Regular", Avenir, Arial, sans-serif; !important
 }

 a {
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
color: #b1997b;
font-size: 1em;
display: inline;
 }

 a:hover{ 
text-decoration: underline;

 }


 .input {
font-family: "AvenirNext-Regular", Avenir, Arial, sans-serif;
display: block; 
height: 3em; 
width: 20em;
margin: 0 auto;
border: none;
border-bottom: 0.05em solid #9C9B9B;
 }

 h3 {
font-size: 1em;
color: #84A0B1;
font-weight: 600;
line-height: 1.3em;
display: inline;
font-family: "AvenirNext-Regular", Avenir, Arial, sans-serif;
 }
 h2 {
margin-top: 1.3em; !important
font-family: "AvenirNext-Regular", Avenir, Arial, sans-serif; !important
 }
 b, strong {
font-weight: 600;
 }
 .buttonText {
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
color: #84A0B1;
font-size: 1.2em;
display: inline;
 }
 blueColor {
color: #84A0B1;
 }
 brownColor {
color: #b1997b;
 }
 hr {
display: block;
 }

 grayColor {
color: #9C9B9B;
 }
 samp {
display: none;
 }


 .submitbutton{

display: block;  /* inline for text and button */

border: 0.1em; 
border-radius: 0.5em;
background-color: #e6e5e5; 
width: 14em; 
height: 3.5em;
outline-color: #C0C0C0;


text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
color: #84A0B1;
font-size: 0.7em;
 }

.offColor {
background-color: #c7c7c7;
 }
 .canceler {
display: block;
margin: 0.5em;
border: 0.1em;
border-radius: 0.5em;
background-color: #e6e5e5;
width: 6em;
height: 3em;
outline-color: #C0C0C0;
 }
 .linktext{
display: inline;
margin: 0.5em;
text-align: left;
color: #84A0B1;
font-size: 1em;
 }
.hidden { 
display: none; 
 }

/* Start by setting display:none to make this hidden.
   Then we position it in relation to the viewport window
   with position:fixed. Width, height, top and left speak
   for themselves. Background we set to 80% white with
   our animation centered, and no-repeating */
.modal {
display:      inherit;
margin-left:  auto;
margin-right: auto;
position:     fixed;
z-index:      1000;
top:          0;
left:         0;
height:       12.5em;
width:        10em;
border-style: none;
z-index:      1002;
}
 .centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
 /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     }

.overlay {
position:fixed;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
opacity:0.8;
z-index:1001;
}
.stop {display: none;}

.show {display: block;}
```

And here is the html for the page:

```
<body>  
            <!-- Locations --!>
        <h2 class = "h2 locations"  style = "text-align: center;">look for your location</h2>



        <hr class="locations" style = "margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em"></hr>


        <p class="locations" style = "display: block; text-align: center">california</p>

             <hr class="locations" style = "margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em"></hr>
                <div style = "display: -webkit-flex; -webkit-align-items: center;  display: flex; align-items: center;">
                    <div style = "-webkit-flex: 1;  flex: 1; display: block; margin-left: 1.5em; min-width: 13em">
                        <h3 class="locations" style = "display: block" >beverly hills</h3>
                        <p class="locations" style = "display: block">9873 S. Santa Monica Blvd.<br> Beverly Hills, CA 90212</p>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" style = "width: 10em; margin-right: 2em" class="locations submitbutton" name="beverlyHills" id = "beverly hills"><p class = "buttonText">select</p></button>
                </div>
            <hr class="locations" style = "margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em"></hr>
                <div style = "display: -webkit-flex; -webkit-align-items: center;  display: flex; align-items: center;">
                    <div style = "-webkit-flex: 1;  flex: 1; display: block; margin-left: 1.5em; min-width: 13em">
                        <h3 class="locations" style = "display: block"">dana point</h3>
                        <p class="locations" style = "display: block">34241 E. Pacific Coast Hwy, Ste. 201 <br> Dana Point, CA 92629 </p>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" style = "width: 10em; margin-right: 2em" class="locations submitbutton" name="danaPoint" id = "dana point"><p class = "buttonText">select</p></button>   
                </div>

            <hr class="locations" style = "margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em"></hr>
                <div style = "display: -webkit-flex; -webkit-align-items: center;  display: flex; align-items: center;">
                    <div style = "-webkit-flex: 1;  flex: 1; display: block; margin-left: 1.5em; min-width: 13em">
                        <h3 class="locations" style = "display: block">manhattan beach</h3>
                        <p class="locations" style = "display: block">3713 Highland Ave, 2nd Floor<br> Manhattan Beach, CA 90266</p>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" style = "width: 10em; margin-right: 2em" class="locations submitbutton" name="manhattanBeach" id = "manhattan beach"><p class = "buttonText">select</p></button>
                </div>
            <hr class="locations" style = "margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em"></hr>
                <div style = "display: -webkit-flex; -webkit-align-items: center;  display: flex; align-items: center;">
                    <div style = "-webkit-flex: 1;  flex: 1; display: block; margin-left: 1.5em; min-width: 13em">
                        <h3 class="locations" style = "display: block">newport beach</h3>
                        <p class="locations" style = "display: block">2744 East Coast Hwy, 2nd Floor <br>Newport Beach, CA 92625</p>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" style = "width: 10em; margin-right: 2em" class="locations submitbutton" name="newportBeach" id = "newport beach"><p class = "buttonText">select</p></button>
                </div>
            <hr class="locations" style = "margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em"></hr>
                <div style = "display: -webkit-flex; -webkit-align-items: center;  display: flex; align-items: center;">
                    <div style = "-webkit-flex: 1;  flex: 1; display: block; margin-left: 1.5em; min-width: 13em">
                        <h3 class="locations" style = "display: block">santa monica</h3>
                        <p class="locations" style = "display: block">1229 Montana Ave, 2nd Floor<br> Santa Monica, CA 90403</p>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" style = "width: 10em; margin-right: 2em" class="locations submitbutton" name="santaMonica" id = "santa monica"><p class = "buttonText">select</p></button>
                </div>




            <hr class="locations" style = "margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em"></hr>


        <p class="locations" style = "display: block; text-align: center">new york</p>

            <hr class="locations" style = "margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em"></hr>
                <div style = "display: -webkit-flex; -webkit-align-items: center;  display: flex; align-items: center;">
                    <div style = "-webkit-flex: 1;  flex: 1; display: block; margin-left: 1.5em; min-width: 13em">
                        <h3 class="locations" style = "display: block">union square</h3>
                        <p class="locations" style = "display: block">114 4th Ave.<br> New York, NY 10003 </p>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" style = "width: 10em; margin-right: 2em" class="locations submitbutton" name="unionSquare" id = "union square"><p class = "buttonText">select</p></button>
                </div>

            <hr class="locations" style = "margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em"></hr>



        <p class="locations" style = "display: block; text-align: center">pennsylvania</p>

            <hr class="locations" style = "margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em"></hr>
                <div style = "display: -webkit-flex; -webkit-align-items: center;  display: flex; align-items: center;">
                    <div style = "-webkit-flex: 1;  flex: 1; display: block; margin-left: 1.5em; min-width: 13em">
                        <h3 class="locations" style = "display: block">philadelphia</h3>
                        <p class="locations" style = "display: block">1120 Walnut St. <br> Philadelphia, PA 19107</p>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" style = "width: 10em; margin-right: 2em" class="locations submitbutton" name="philadelphia" id = "philadelphia"><p class = "buttonText">select</p></button>
                </div>


    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read your question over and over (downvote phobia),
why not back to the simple way.

You said, Override for a single page only, didn't you?
Have you tried register your *custom single page stylesheet* using `wp_enqueue_style` in the bottom of your functions.php? like this:

```
function your_single_page_stylesheet(){

  if($this_is_your_page_id_or_slug){
    //run
    wp_enqueue_style( 'page-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/page-custom.css' );
  }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_single_page_stylesheet', 100);
```

or maybe, you could unregister your parent/default stylesheet with [dequeue](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style) function like this,

```
function your_single_page_stylesheet(){

  if($this_isi_your_page_id_or_slug){
    //first dequeue 
    wp_dequeue_style( 'default-stylesheet' );

    //enqueue new style
    wp_enqueue_style( 'page-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/page-custom.css' );
  }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_single_page_stylesheet', 100);
```

Comment: You could change  `$this_isi_your_page_id_or_slug` to `is_home()`, `is_page()` or else.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a scoping class to the body of your page `<body class="this-page-class">...</body>`and have rules that only apply to those classes scoped by that class.

Comment: Specifically, using WordPress's [`body_class()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/)

Comment: Alright so I added <body class = "booking"> </body>  around my html and then in the stylesheet I surrounded the whole thing with .booking {} but to no avail @mevius

Comment: The way you have it right now your stylesheet will look for a body tag inside of something with a booking class, rather than applying to a body with class `booking`. In order for it to apply, it's likely you'll have to do `body.booking` and ensure that any additional body's are not inside that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason that surrounding the new page's body in a class is not working is because that is simply making it more specific, so all the rules from the CSS sheet are still applying to everything within that class.  I suggest removing that and adding a new stylesheet as the solution.

In your "header.PHP" file you can add if statements to the link to the CSS sheet to get the desired result.  If/then statements would work as well.

Something like this would call out one stylesheet for common "page.php" pages and a different stylesheet for a page operated by "newpage.php":

```
<?php
if ( is_page_template('page.php')) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css" />
<?php } ?>
<?php
if ( is_page_template('newpage.php')) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/newpage.css" />
<?php } ?>
```

Here is blog post that goes into more detail:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-have-a-separate-stylecss-for-each-page-template